# guardar data ajax en array

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde al presionar un Item de la tabla realizo una consulta en `Ajax` esta me devuelve un resultado un listado de item. Estoy declarando un `Array()` para luego poder guardar este listado en el.

```
     $('#table tbody tr> td').click(function() {
                      var pieza = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4)').text();
                      var piezas = [];
                      $.ajax({
                        data:  {'pieza':pieza},
                        url:   'JSON/likeJSON.php',
                        type:  'POST',
                        cache: false,
                        success:  function (data)
                        {
            //Con la Ayuda de @Sr1871 y @Fran Islas logre poder desplegar el listado.
            //Pero lo que ocurre ahora es que si selecciono otra pieza en la tabla,
            //el listado no cambia, ya que mi JSON realizo un Where item like '%%'                       
                        data = JSON.parse(data);
                        for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {

                            piezas.push({
                                value: count,
                                text: '' + data[count].pieza + ''
                            })

                        }
                    },
                        async: false
                      });

                      $('#table').editable({
                          container: 'body',
                          selector: 'td.Pieza',
                          title: 'Pieza Nueva',
                          type: "POST",
                          source:piezas,
                          showbuttons: false,
                          select2: {
                              width: 200,
                              placeholder: 'Nueva Pieza',
                              allowClear: true
                          },
                          success: function() {

                          }
                      });

                    })
```

Como puedo guardar la `data` en mi array en Javascritps para luego poder usar este `Array()` como `source` en mi metodo editable.

**Con la Ayuda de @Sr1871 y @Fran Islas logre poder desplegar el listado. Pero lo que ocurre ahora es que si selecciono otra pieza este listado no cambia y mi likeJSON veo la nueva data.**

Espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: estás usando x-editable? has probado si también funciona con jsons en lugar de objetos? de ser así ni siquiera tendrías que guardarlo en un array, sino guradar directamente el objeto que regresa el data

Comment: si estoy utilizando x-editable, y quiero que el source del select sea el `Array()` de Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A través de la función   JSON.parse  podemos transformar una cadena de caracteres con formato JSON en un objeto de JavaScript. Por otro lado, la función  JSON.stringify  permite obtener el resultado inverso: transforma un objeto JavaScript en una cadena de texto con formato JSON.

```
ajaxGet("http://localhost:3000/imagenes", function(respuesta) {
  // Transformación de formato JSON a JavaScript
  var imagenes = []; // nueva instancia
  imagenes = JSON.parse(respuesta);
  console.log(imagenes);
});
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Editado: Prueba agregando `var imagenes = []; // nueva instancia`

Comment: Me funciona bien pero el array queda con los texto del primer click, como podria vaciar el array para luego llenarlo con la `data` nueva

Comment: Lo agregue y no cambia, también implemente el `piezas.length = 0;`

Comment: Y si saco la var `pieza` afuera del evento click este me limpia, pero despues no me deja seleccionar una pieza!

Comment: La verdad que no te estoy entendiendo bien. Has probado **DECLARAR** piezas y pieza fuera del evento y lugo **INSTANCIAR** ambos al comienzo del evento? Algo asi: **fuera del evento**  ( `var pieza = '';  var piezas = [];` ) **Dentro del evento** 
 (`pieza = '';  piezas = [];` ).

Comment: Lo repare  en vez de declarar la variable `value` debe ser `id` https://stackoverflow.com/a/15940513/8766401

Answer (score 1):

La documentación pide que tenga los campos `value` y  `text` si es array

documentación : https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#select

así que simplemente puedes hacer

```
for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {

   piezas.push({value : count, text: data[count].pieza})

}
```

También se podría hacer con map

```
success:  function (data) {
    piezas = data.map(function(simpleData){
        return {value :simpleData.valor', text : simpleData.pieza}
    })
}
```

Esto puede ser un mejor uso si tu valor viene del data del ajax, sino puedes usar el `for`

Comment: Me muestra este error `TypeError: text is undefined[Aprender más]
select2.js:362:13` le agrege  text: ''+data[count].pieza+'' y me muestra un listado con este texto `undefined`

Comment: Antes del `for` agrega esto `data = JSON.parse(data);` pero el listado del select me queda con los texto del primer select :(

Comment: me faltaron los dos puntos en el text dle for, pruebalo de nuevo, lo he editado

Comment: Debes agregar `text: '' + data[count].pieza + ''`  porque el text es `string`, y aparte `data = JSON.parse(data);` para la data a string. Lo que me ocurre ahora es que el listado del select no se modifica me queda con el primero

Comment: Explica mejor esa parte ya que no la entiendo, edita tu pregunta y agrega más información

Comment: listo la edite, si saco la var `piezas` afuera del evento click este me limpia y me carga con datos nuevos pero no me deja seleccionar una pieza!